# What happens if you fail the final mission when playing Ironman mode?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm playing through on Classic Ironman and it's been seriously tough so far. I've got my third best squad (please don't ask about the other two, it's still a sensitive matter) to the start of the temple assault, but haven't yet started it as I'm not sure what will happen if I fail. Is it totally game over? Or do I get the chance to train up a new squad a try again?

Comment: If it's anything like the original it's game over if you fail. I haven't played the new game yet so I can't say 100% - hence this is not an answer.

Comment: I played on normal, and when I lost the important soldier in the final mission I received a non-standard game over message. The iron man mode will certainly not be any more forgiving. When you really want to find out, create a backup of your save and lose on purpose (it's not cheating when it's FOR SCIENCE).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit:

Ok - in the interest of science I have tested this out fully. You will always be given a 'restart mission' option if your volunteer dies.

I have tested this on the following difficulties;

- Easy
- Ironman Normal
- Ironman Classic
- Ironman Impossible

They all give you a 'restart mission' choice. The non ironman also gives you a 'load last save game' option.

As other people have reported, some people think they have seen a "game over" message when you fail, myself included. I suspected this answer might have changed after the first patch, where they made some changes.

Comment: Did you verify this? Because several people on forums have reported that it lets you retry the final mission even on Iron Man. Not sure if it's just a rumor circling around or actually a feature - but I'll test it out if I manage to get to the last mission on my Ironman playthrough. :)

Comment: ...and now I've asked this question in the official XCOM forums, and received an answer that you get a chance to retry both the final and first mission, even in Iron Man. I've only tested it for the first mission, but it seems legit. http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?192721-Iron-Man-and-the-Final-Mission

Comment: @idan315 - answer changed

Comment: bravo, Sir.  If I could +1 you FOR SCIENCE any more, I would have done.

Comment: So on the Ironman mode, if you restart mission, do you at least need to send a different volunteer?

Comment: @Dronz - no - it just restarts the mission from the beginning - i.e. as if it never occurred.